# Ошибка: нарушения доступа чтения

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, память, visual-studio-2017

Имеется программа, которая пересекает 2 многоугольника (std::vector RealSector(1), std::vector MirrorSector(1);). Количество пересеченных точек сокращается (std::vector SendForSaving(1)) до ~50 путем записи в std::vector SendForSaving(1) не всех точек с учетом, что есть так называемые "важные точки" (POINT VIPdots[6]). Все это дело параллельно отрисовывается посередине экрана с помощью метода Polygon (POINT *...). В дополнительном окошке отрисовывается то, что будет сохранено.
Возникает проблема при запуске и может выдать 2 вида ошибок (см. рисунки). Обе пишут о нарушении доступа при чтении, хотя, как мне кажется, с выделением и освобождением памяти проблем нет.
В чем может быть причина ошибок и как исправить.
Спасибо.
[image: Первый вариант ошибки]
[image: Второй вариант ошибки]

```
// NewClippingDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "NewClipping.h"
#include "NewClippingDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "clipper.hpp"
#include <gdiplusgraphics.h>
#include "gdiplusgraphics.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#define PI 3.1415926535
#endif


// CNewClippingDlg dialog

using namespace ClipperLib;

CNewClippingDlg::CNewClippingDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_NEWCLIPPING_DIALOG, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CNewClippingDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER1, SectorSlider);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER2, XSlider);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER3, YSlider);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER4, RadiusSlider);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER5, AngleSlider);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK1, CheckSave);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT7, FirstCts);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT8, SecondCds);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK2, DrawStart);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK3, CheckDrawSaving);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CNewClippingDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CNewClippingDlg::AddMirrorLine)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CNewClippingDlg::Activate)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_HSCROLL()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CNewClippingDlg::SaveCoordinates)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &CNewClippingDlg::IfChecking)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CNewClippingDlg message handlers

BOOL CNewClippingDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

int X1, Y1, X2, Y2, CenterX, CenterY, StatusLButton = 0, CounterClicks = 0,
    DrawCircles = 0, DrawSolution = 0, NumberOfFile = 0, CON = 0, CenterSmallX, CenterSmallY;
double Step = 1;
long double idouble/*, PI = 3.1415926535*/;
RECT WindowRect;
CRect DrawRect, DrawSavingRect;
std::vector<Path> RealSector(1);
std::vector<Path> MirrorSector(1);
std::vector<Path> SolutionSector(2);
std::vector<Path> SendForSaving(1);
POINT *RealSectorStruct;
POINT *MirrorSectorStruct;
POINT **SolutionStruct;
POINT *FormRealCircle(int XSlider, int YSlider, int AngleSlider, int SectorSlider, int RadiusSlider);
POINT *FormMirrorCircle(POINT *RealSectorStruct, int SectorSlider);
POINT **SolutionCircle(std::vector<Path> SubjectSector, std::vector<Path> ClipperSector);
CString TextForLine, FileName, DirectPathName, ForNumber;
ofstream file;
void SaveCoordinatesFunction();
POINT VIPdots[6];
int VIPDraw = 0;
int k = 0;
POINT *DrawWhatInSave;
int neededsize = 0, WriteHappend = 0;
int CustomSize = 0, CustomStep = 0;
POINT *FormStructForSave(POINT **SolutionStruct);

void CNewClippingDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;
        CWnd* m_hWnd = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();
        m_hWnd->MoveWindow(0, 0, 100, 100);

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        CPen p(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0)), p1(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 255, 0)), p2(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 255));
        if (CenterX != 0 && CenterY != 0) {
            dc.Rectangle(DrawRect);
            dc.Rectangle(DrawSavingRect);
        }
        if (X1 != 0 && Y1 != 0 && X2 != 0 && Y2 != 0) {
            dc.MoveTo(X1, Y1);
            dc.LineTo(X2, Y2);
        }
        if (DrawCircles == 1) {
            dc.Polygon(RealSectorStruct, 362 - SectorSlider.GetPos());
            dc.Polygon(MirrorSectorStruct, 362 - SectorSlider.GetPos());
        }
        if (DrawSolution != 0) {
            dc.SelectObject(p);
            for (int i = 0; i < DrawSolution; i++) {
                dc.Polygon(SolutionStruct[i], SolutionSector[i].size());
                if (DrawStart.GetCheck() == 1) {
                    dc.Ellipse(SolutionStruct[i][0].x - 3, SolutionStruct[i][0].y - 3, SolutionStruct[i][0].x + 3, SolutionStruct[i][0].y + 3);
                }
            }
        }
        if (VIPDraw == 1) {
            dc.SelectObject(p1);
            for (int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
                dc.Ellipse(VIPdots[i].x - 3, VIPdots[i].y - 3, VIPdots[i].x + 3, VIPdots[i].y + 3);
            }
        }
        if (neededsize > 0 && CheckDrawSaving.GetCheck() == 1){
            dc.SelectObject(p2);
            dc.Polygon(DrawWhatInSave, neededsize);
        }
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CNewClippingDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CNewClippingDlg::AddMirrorLine()
{
    StatusLButton = 1;
}

void CNewClippingDlg::Activate()
{
    GetClientRect(&WindowRect);
    CenterX = (WindowRect.left + WindowRect.right) / 2;
    CenterY = (WindowRect.top + WindowRect.bottom) / 2;
    CenterSmallX = CenterX - 325;
    CenterSmallY = CenterY;
    DrawRect.left = CenterX - 225;
    DrawRect.top = CenterY - 225;
    DrawRect.right = CenterX + 225;
    DrawRect.bottom = CenterY + 225;
    DrawSavingRect.left = CenterX - 405;
    DrawSavingRect.top = CenterY - 80;
    DrawSavingRect.right = CenterX - 245;
    DrawSavingRect.bottom = CenterY + 80;
    XSlider.SetRange(75, 375, 1);
    XSlider.SetPos(225);
    YSlider.SetRange(75, 375, 1);
    YSlider.SetPos(225);
    AngleSlider.SetRange(0, 360, 1);
    AngleSlider.SetPos(0);
    RadiusSlider.SetRange(10, 75, 1);
    RadiusSlider.SetPos(75);
    SectorSlider.SetRange(0, 360, 1);
    SectorSlider.SetPos(90);
    CheckDrawSaving.SetCheck(1);
    InvalidateRect(DrawRect, 1);
    InvalidateRect(DrawSavingRect, 1);
    OnPaint();
}


void CNewClippingDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    int Coords[4];
    if (StatusLButton == 1) {
        CounterClicks++;
        if (CounterClicks == 1) {
            Coords[0] = point.x;
            Coords[1] = point.y;
            X1 = Coords[0];
            Y1 = Coords[1];
        }
    }
    if (StatusLButton == 1 && CounterClicks == 2) {
        Coords[2] = point.x;
        Coords[3] = point.y;
        X2 = Coords[2];
        Y2 = Coords[3];
        StatusLButton = 0;
        CounterClicks = 0;
        DrawCircles = 1;
        RealSectorStruct = FormRealCircle(XSlider.GetPos() - 225, YSlider.GetPos() - 225, AngleSlider.GetPos(), SectorSlider.GetPos(), RadiusSlider.GetPos());
        MirrorSectorStruct = FormMirrorCircle(RealSectorStruct, SectorSlider.GetPos());
        SolutionStruct = SolutionCircle(RealSector, MirrorSector);
        DrawWhatInSave = FormStructForSave(SolutionStruct);
        InvalidateRect(DrawRect, 1);
        InvalidateRect(DrawSavingRect, 1);
        OnPaint();
        TextForLine.Format(_T("(%d; %d)"), X1, Y1);
        FirstCts.SetWindowTextW(TextForLine);
        TextForLine.Format(_T("(%d; %d)"), X2, Y2);
        SecondCds.SetWindowTextW(TextForLine);
        XSlider.EnableWindow(true);
        YSlider.EnableWindow(true);
        AngleSlider.EnableWindow(true);
        RadiusSlider.EnableWindow(true);
        SectorSlider.EnableWindow(true);
        delete[] RealSectorStruct;
        delete[] MirrorSectorStruct;
        delete[] SolutionStruct;
        delete[] DrawWhatInSave;
    }

    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}

POINT *FormRealCircle(int XSlider, int YSlider, int AngleSlider, int SectorSlider, int RadiusSlider) {
    if (DrawCircles == 1) {
        RealSectorStruct = new POINT[362 - SectorSlider];
        RealSector[0].clear();
        for (int i = 0 + AngleSlider; i < 362 + AngleSlider - SectorSlider; i++) {
            idouble = (long double)i;
            RealSector[0] << IntPoint((CenterX + XSlider + RadiusSlider * cos(idouble*(PI / 180)))*pow(10.0, 6.0),
                (CenterY + YSlider + RadiusSlider * sin(idouble*(PI / 180)))*pow(10.0, 6.0));
            RealSectorStruct[i - AngleSlider].x = CenterX + XSlider + RadiusSlider * cos(idouble*(PI / 180));
            RealSectorStruct[i - AngleSlider].y = CenterY + YSlider + RadiusSlider * sin(idouble*(PI / 180));
        }
        RealSector[0] << IntPoint((CenterX + XSlider)*pow(10.0, 6.0), (CenterY + YSlider)*pow(10.0, 6.0));
        RealSectorStruct[362 - SectorSlider - 1].x = CenterX + XSlider;
        RealSectorStruct[362 - SectorSlider - 1].y = CenterY + YSlider;
        return RealSectorStruct;
    }
}

POINT *FormMirrorCircle(POINT *RealSectorStruct, int SectorSlider) {
    long double k, X0, Y0;
    long double dX1 = (long double)X1;
    long double dY1 = (long double)Y1;
    long double dX2 = (long double)X2;
    long double dY2 = (long double)Y2;
    MirrorSectorStruct = new POINT[362 - SectorSlider];
    MirrorSector[0].clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 362 - SectorSlider; i++) {
        k = -1 * ((dX2 - dX1)*(dX1 - RealSectorStruct[i].x) + (dY2 - dY1)*(dY1 - RealSectorStruct[i].y)) /
            ((dX2 - dX1)*(dX2 - RealSectorStruct[i].x) + (dY2 - dY1)*(dY2 - RealSectorStruct[i].y));
        X0 = (dX1 + k * dX2) / (1 + k);
        Y0 = (dY1 + k * dY2) / (1 + k);
        MirrorSector[0] << IntPoint(int(2 * X0 - RealSectorStruct[i].x)*pow(10.0, 6.0), int(2 * Y0 - RealSectorStruct[i].y)*pow(10.0, 6.0));
        MirrorSectorStruct[i].x = int(2 * X0 - RealSectorStruct[i].x);
        MirrorSectorStruct[i].y = int(2 * Y0 - RealSectorStruct[i].y);
    }
    return MirrorSectorStruct;
};

POINT **SolutionCircle(std::vector<Path> SubjectSector, std::vector<Path> ClipperSector) {
    VIPDraw = 0;
    SolutionSector.clear();
    Clipper DoClip;
    DoClip.AddPath(SubjectSector[0], ptSubject, true);
    DoClip.AddPath(ClipperSector[0], ptClip, true);
    DoClip.Execute(ctIntersection, SolutionSector, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);
    if (SolutionSector.size() != 0) {
        SolutionStruct = new POINT*[SolutionSector.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < SolutionSector.size(); i++) {
            SolutionStruct[i] = new POINT[SolutionSector[i].size()];
            for (int j = 0; j < SolutionSector[i].size(); j++) {
                SolutionStruct[i][j].x = SolutionSector[i][j].X / pow(10.0, 6.0);
                SolutionStruct[i][j].y = SolutionSector[i][j].Y / pow(10.0, 6.0);
            }
            DrawSolution = i + 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SolutionSector.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SolutionSector[i].size(); j++) {
                if ((abs(SolutionStruct[i][j].x - SolutionStruct[i][j + 1].x) > 5 ||
                    abs(SolutionStruct[i][j].y - SolutionStruct[i][j + 1].y) > 5) && j != SolutionSector[i].size() - 1) {
                    VIPdots[k].x = SolutionStruct[i][j].x;
                    VIPdots[k].y = SolutionStruct[i][j].y;
                    VIPdots[k + 1].x = SolutionStruct[i][j + 1].x;
                    VIPdots[k + 1].y = SolutionStruct[i][j + 1].y;
                    k = k + 2;
                    VIPDraw = 1;
                }
                if (j == SolutionSector[i].size() - 1) {
                    if ((abs(SolutionStruct[i][j].x - SolutionStruct[i][0].x) > 5 ||
                        abs(SolutionStruct[i][j].y - SolutionStruct[i][0].y) > 5))
                    VIPdots[k].x = SolutionStruct[i][j].x;
                    VIPdots[k].y = SolutionStruct[i][j].y;
                }
            }
        }
        return SolutionStruct;
    }
    else {
        DrawSolution = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}

void CNewClippingDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CSliderCtrl *pSlider = reinterpret_cast<CSliderCtrl*>(pScrollBar);
    if (pSlider == &XSlider || pSlider == &YSlider || pSlider == &AngleSlider || pSlider == &SectorSlider || pSlider == &RadiusSlider) {
        k = 0;
        RealSectorStruct = FormRealCircle(XSlider.GetPos() - 225, YSlider.GetPos() - 225, AngleSlider.GetPos(), SectorSlider.GetPos(), RadiusSlider.GetPos());
        MirrorSectorStruct = FormMirrorCircle(RealSectorStruct, SectorSlider.GetPos());
        SolutionStruct = SolutionCircle(RealSector, MirrorSector);
        DrawWhatInSave = FormStructForSave(SolutionStruct);
        if (CheckSave.GetCheck() == 1) {
            SaveCoordinatesFunction();
        }
        InvalidateRect(DrawRect, 1);
        InvalidateRect(DrawSavingRect, 1);
        OnPaint();
        delete[] RealSectorStruct;
        delete[] MirrorSectorStruct;
        delete[] SolutionStruct;
        delete[] DrawWhatInSave;
    }
    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

void CNewClippingDlg::SaveCoordinates()
{
    if (SolutionSector.size() != 1) {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Секторы не пересекаются или пересечение не односвязно"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else {
        SaveCoordinatesFunction();
    }
}

void SaveCoordinatesFunction() {
    if (SendForSaving.size() == 1) {
        if (DirectPathName == "") {
            CFileDialog SFile(false, _T(".txt"), _T("Example 1"), 0, _T("TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt|"));
            SFile.DoModal();
            DirectPathName = SFile.GetFolderPath();
        }
        NumberOfFile++;
        ForNumber.Format(_T("%d"), NumberOfFile);
        FileName = DirectPathName + _T("\\Example ") + ForNumber + _T(".txt");
        file.open(FileName, ios::out);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SendForSaving[0].size(); i++) {
                file << SendForSaving[0][i].X << " " << SendForSaving[0][i].Y << endl;
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }
}

POINT *FormStructForSave(POINT **SolutionStruct)
{
    if (SolutionSector.size() != 0) {
        neededsize = 0;
        WriteHappend = 0;
        DrawWhatInSave = new POINT[SolutionSector[0].size()];
        //for (int i = 0; i < SolutionSector.size(); i++) {
            if (SolutionSector[0].size() > 50) {
                CustomStep = ceil(SolutionSector[0].size() / 50) + 1;
                CustomSize = (SolutionSector[0].size() / CustomStep) + 6;
            }
            else {
                CustomSize = SolutionSector[0].size();
                CustomStep = 1;
            }
            DrawWhatInSave = new POINT[CustomSize];
            for (int j = 0; j < SolutionSector[0].size(); j++) {
                WriteHappend = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                    if (SolutionStruct[0][j].x == VIPdots[k].x && SolutionStruct[0][j].y == VIPdots[k].y) {
                        DrawWhatInSave[neededsize].x = CenterSmallX - (CenterX - SolutionStruct[0][j].x);
                        DrawWhatInSave[neededsize].y = CenterSmallY - (CenterY - SolutionStruct[0][j].y);
                        neededsize++;
                        WriteHappend = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (WriteHappend == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    if (j % CustomStep == 0) {
                        DrawWhatInSave[neededsize].x = CenterSmallX - (CenterX - SolutionStruct[0][j].x);
                        DrawWhatInSave[neededsize].y = CenterSmallY - (CenterY - SolutionStruct[0][j].y);
                        neededsize++;
                    }
                }
            }
        //}
        SendForSaving[0].clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < neededsize; i++) {
            SendForSaving[0] << IntPoint((DrawWhatInSave[i].x - CenterSmallX + CenterX) * 0.5, (DrawWhatInSave[i].y - CenterSmallY + CenterY) * 0.5);
        }
        return DrawWhatInSave;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void CNewClippingDlg::IfChecking()
{
    if (DirectPathName == "") {
        CFileDialog SFile(false, _T(".txt"), _T("Example 1"), 0, _T("TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt|"));
        SFile.DoModal();
        DirectPathName = SFile.GetFolderPath();
        SaveCoordinatesFunction();
    }
    if (CON % 2 == 0) {
        CON++;
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Включена функция автосохранения.\nПри каждои изменении любого из ползунка будет сохранен новый файл"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else {
        CON++;
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Функция автосохранения отключена"), MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вылет за пределы массива `DrawWhatInSave` при записи, согласно тому, что написано в сообщении об ошибке. Что это вообще за странный код такой: сначала `DrawWhatInSave = new POINT[SolutionSector[0].size()];` и потом вдруг `DrawWhatInSave = new POINT[CustomSize];`? Утечка памяти.

Comment: DrawWhatInSave = new POINT[SolutionSector[0].size()]; - убрал, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: Ну так а что это за размер такой - `CustomSize`? Я не в силах понять магию ваших хитрых вычислений этого `CustomSize`. Поставьте в коде проверки на то, что этого `CustomSize` действительно достаточно. Любой уважающий себя код должен быть под завязку набит assertions на эту тему. У вас же ничего даже близко похожего нет.

Comment: CustomSize определяет размер "урезанного" пересечения (SolutionSector[0].size()]). Например, пересечение (SolutionSector[0].size()]) имеет размер 230 точек, а надо не более 50, значит сначала считаем CustomStep - (230/50) + 1 = 6. CustomSize - 230/6 + 6 (для "важных точек") = 38 + 6 = 44 точки - сколько и требовалось.
Впредь буду добавлять assertions.

Comment: Довольно долго программирую на С++ и за всё время ни разу ровно не проходило с new и delete а тут я вижу delete[] RealSectorStruct; и такого полно. Где такая прекрасная вещь как vector? У него и проверки есть на выход за пределы. shared_ptr ещё есть. А каждый раз как вижу delete вспоминаю сколько проблем это создаёт.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена.
Ошибка была в выделении памяти для DrawWhatInSave. Нужно выделить количество памяти, равное размеру SolutionSector[0].